# angularjs compile ng-controller and interpolation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector) I saw an example of compiling "something" added later.

```
var $div = $('<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">{{content.label}}</div>');
$(document.body).append($div);

angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
  var scope = angular.element($div).scope();
  $compile($div)(scope);
});
```

I've added **this** code on a jquery ready function, but I have two problems:

First is an error:
 `Argument 'MyCtrl' is not a function, got undefined`.

The second is that I don't know how to make that `content.label` works! I've added it to the `scope` but it doesn't work. How should I call my controller to see working the data binding of `content.label`?

MY FINAL MODIFIED CODE IS:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

    $(function(){

        app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){
            $scope.content = 123;
        });

        var $div = $('<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">{{content}}</div>');
        $(document.body).append($div);

        angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
          var scope = angular.element($div).scope();
          $compile($div)(scope);
        });

    });
```

Comment: Does your code above have errors? (Such as `$scope.content` isn't defined?) - are you including the JS?

Comment: please take a look at the edit. The only error is the one shown above

Comment: You can derive from the html that label is a property of content. ($scope.content.label = "something" or $scope.content = { label : "something" };)

Comment: ok, I know that, but how can I make it works?

Comment: Is scope null or undefined when you assign it?

Comment: It works [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ttYwVHxMms9b3r4dhc1o).

Comment: @skubski have you read my desc? On the docs.... "something" **added later**. I`ve also shared the docs link to see more info "This is fairly rare but could be the case if a third party library is injecting the markup"

Comment: Yeps, you are right. Whenever it is added after the bootstrap or by a third party library a digest/apply needs to be triggered to tell angular that it got changed from outside of its system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You should start a digest cycle after compiling new markup, in order to build all bindings and fire watchers. This can be done by calling `scope.$digest();` :

```
$compile($div)(scope);
scope.$digest();
```

The result should look like:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
  app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){
      $scope.content = 123;
  });

  angular.element(document).ready(function () {
      var $div = $('<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">{{content}}  </div>');
      $(document.body).append($div);

      angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
        var scope = angular.element($div).scope();
        $compile($div)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
      });

  });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/dDNBxf8SowKTPgnVj0tF?p=preview

Comment: I do have that attribute

Comment: Only a $digest (or $apply) needs to be triggered, unless there there is no JQuery library available (or loaded before angular is). Seems to be the correct answer.

Comment: I am convinced that in @Barbu Barbu case the error "Argument 'MyCtrl' is not a function, got undefined." beacuse of using jquery `.ready()`. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, yes. The thruth is yours. I will update my answer. Thanks once again!

Comment: with $apply or $disgest, now works! that solved my problem. thanks!

Comment: In my case, I am following the same example, however, the code `angular.element(document).injector()` is returning `undefined`, why?